# Unable to get reference to HasOne Property Inside Remote Method

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, relation

I have `ExtentedUser` Model which has two `hasOne` relationships to two models

> `driver and customer` (both having a `belongTo` realtionship back to the `ExtentedUser`) and they are also the Extended from User base model).
>
> after the use of

```
 ExtentedUser.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next){

         //in here i am unable to get
        // reference to driver or customer model
      //eg user.driver or user.customer
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad what i was doing wrong is that i using model name as property.

```
   user.driver /where driver is modelName
```

but i should have used the relationship name 
which was

```
   user.drivers /where drivers is RelationShipName
```